Dependabot not raising automated pull requests for Gradle dependencies
I have the following dependabot.yml configuration:
version: 2
updates:
- package-ecosystem: "gradle"
directory: "/"
schedule:
interval: "daily"
target-branch: "main"
open-pull-requests-limit: 0
My build.gradle file contains the following dependencies:
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

apply from: './versions.gradle'

group = 'com.github.jitpack'
version = '2.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8 // java 8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation "commons-io:commons-io:2.16.1"
  implementation "com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.4.17"
  implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7"
  implementation "com.google.guava:guava:32.0.0-jre"
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1"
}

java {
    withSourcesJar()
    withJavadocJar()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
        from components.java
        }
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "7.3.3"
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}

In the repository settings, I have enabled "Dependabot alerts" and "Dependabot security updates."
Despite the configuration, Dependabot is not raising any automated pull requests to update the dependencies in my project. I'm not sure what the issue could be or if there's anything I'm missing in the setup.

You need to publish the dependency graph to gradle for dependabot to work in gradle projects.
More details can be found here https://github.com/gradle/actions/blob/main/docs/setup-gradle.md

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
